# Uncertainty in energy for 1D harmonic oscillator in a coherent state

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises

Coherent states for a one-dimensional harmonic oscillator are given by:

$$|\alpha\rangle = e^{-|\alpha|^{2}/2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\alpha^{n}}{\sqrt{n!}}|n\rangle$$ **

($|n\rangle$ is an eigen state of the harmonic oscillator)

Books typically demonstrate the process for finding the uncertainty in position $\Delta x$ and in momentum $\Delta p$.
But, what if we wanted to find the uncertainty in energy $\Delta E$.

Specifically, if we wanted to find ∆E using ∆E = $\sqrt{\langle E^{2}\rangle - \langle E\rangle^{2}}$ , how would we proceed to find $\langle E\rangle$ and $\langle E^{2}\rangle$?

Comment: You may want to use `\langle` and `\rangle`, and to Jax the `\Delta`s. Nonetheless, good question! Welcome to Physics StackExchange!

Comment: $|\alpha \rangle$ is a linear combination of **energy eigen-state** of quantum harmonic oscillator $|n \rangle$. The modulus squared of coefficient corresponds to the probability of finding $|\alpha \rangle$ in state $| n \rangle$

Answer (score 1):

The energy operator is the Hamiltonian, i.e. here you need to calculate
$$\langle E^2\rangle = \langle\alpha |\hat{H}^2|\alpha\rangle,\\
\langle E\rangle = \langle\alpha |\hat{H}|\alpha\rangle,$$
which is easy to do, since $|n\rangle$ are the eigenstates of the Hamiltonian.